# How to pass v-model into another v-model

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5

this is my input, i want to put the value to password equals with ic_number without retyping again in password input. can we pass the ic_number to password v-model?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Ic Number</label>
    <input
        id="ic_number"
        placeholder="Ic Number"
        v-model="form.ic_number"
        type="text"
        name="ic_number"
        class="form-control"
        :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('ic_number') }"
    >
    <has-error :form="form" field="ic_number"></has-error>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input
        id="password"
        placeholder="Password"
        v-model="form.password"
        type="password"
        name="password"
        class="form-control"
        :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('passsword') }"
    >
    <has-error :form="form" field="password"></has-error>
</div>
```

current code in my vuejs application

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      editMode: false,
      users: {},
      form: new Form({
        id: "",
        name: "",
        ic_number:"",
        no_phone:"",
        email: "",
        password: "",
        type: "",
        bio: "",
        photo: ""
      })
    };
  },
```

I want to pass like this but it shows nothing

```
password: password = this.ic_number,
```

Comment: Is this to set the initial value or do you want both of these values to be in sync with each other i.e. they are always the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you'd just like to make the value of the password the same at the ic_number. You can just set that in the v-model directive, like so:

`v-model="form.password = this.form.ic_number"`

Comment: thats i want tq broo

Answer (score 1):

you can use [watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch) for ic_number, when ic_number change ,watch method will be use

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      editMode: false,
      users: {},
      
      id: "",
      name: "",
      ic_number:"",
      no_phone:"",
      email: "",
      password: "",
      type: "",
      bio: "",
      photo: ""
    };
  },
  watch:{
    "ic_number":function(val,oldval){ this.password = val }
  }
}
```

I am not sure do you means A to B and B to C

like this demo

app.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Test1 v-model="hello"></Test1>
    <div>{{hello}}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Test1 from "./components/Test1";

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      hello: "hello"
    };
  },
  components: {
    Test1
  }
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

test1.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="hello">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["value"],
  data() {
    return {
      hello: this.value
    };
  },
  watch: {
    hello: function(val, oldval) {
      this.$emit("input", val);
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Comment: ummm I'm not sure the tags <has-error> and why you use new Form(),

Comment: i use that error tag to show the error,  already work other function, just want to know how to pass from v-model to other v-model

Comment: do you means you have three component ,and C use in B, B use in A ,you want use v-model in A and send to B,and use in B and send to C?

Comment: please see the answer again , I have give you a new demo ,do you means that?

Comment: yes something like that thanks broo, i found another answer.